# LWC search function filter error

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I am trying to implement a search feature on an existing array but I am getting an error stating that 'filter is not a function'. Maybe I am not passing in the correct parameters?

```js
 searchValue = '';  
 stringResult = [];
 fields = ['Name'];    

 this.stringResult = this.sectionInvLineItems;
 this.arrayFields = this.fields;
 this.searchVal = this.searchValue;

 console.log( 'stringResult 2 ' + this.stringResult );  // [object Object]
 console.log( 'arrayFields 2 ' + this.arrayFields );  //returns Name 
 console.log( 'searchVal 2 ' + this.searchVal ); //returns what is being typed 

 const filterData = (stringResult, arrayFields, searchVal) => {
   return stringResult.filter( item => !item[arrayFields].toLowerCase().search(searchVal.toLowerCase()));
 };

 if(  this.searchValue.length > 2 ) {
   const remaining = filterData( this.stringResult, this.arrayFields, this.searchValue );

   this.stringResult = [ ...remaining ];
 }
 else {
   this.displayedItems = [ ...this.stringResult ];
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs because the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method is being called on a string instead of an array (line 18):

```
if(  this.searchValue.length > 2 ) {
  // When filterData is called this.stringResult is equal to a string instead of an array 
  const remaining = filterData( this.stringResult, this.arrayFields, this.searchValue );

  this.stringResult = [ ...remaining ];
}
```

To resolve this error you'll need to update line 5 to set this.stringResult equal to an array.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Tyler. I used JSON.stringify so that I could see the data.  ex:  items":[{"detail":{"Id":"asasasasasasasas","Name":"CI-000003","Section__c":"General Section".  So are you saying do not use JSON.stringify?  stringResult is an array but I need to populate the array?  Or do i keep JSON.stringify and use Object.fromEntries to create the array?  Thnak you.

Comment: If you are only using `JSON.stringify` to view the contents of the variable, then I would recommend moving `JSON.stringify` from line 5 to the console log statement:


`this.stringResult = this.sectionInvLineItems;`


 `console.log( 'stringResult 2 ' + JSON.stringify(this.stringResult));  //returns array data`


This will ensure that the variable is an array instead of a string when you call the `.filter` method.

Comment: Tyler, I made the updates as you suggested so now in the console this.stringResult will render  [object Object] .  When I step through in the  inspector console I can the array data under t : OriginalTarget: Items.  But I am still getting a script error

Comment: Tyler, do you know if the array that holds the fields I am searching against need to be fields = ['Name'] or fields = ['Name:'];

Comment: Hey Tyler.  The issue is that the array keep reading undefined.  Error: ' Cannot read properties of undefined' .  Like I said before I can see the array data under Proxy/Handler which I thought was normal.  Please advise if this could be the issue.  Thanks

Comment: When you say that the array is undefined, do you mean that `stringResult` is undefined in the array function or is it that `item[arrayFields]` is undefined? Also, would you be able to share the entire LWC component? If so, I'd be happy to try running it in my own SF environment to make sure I am not missing something.

Comment: I think I may know what the issue is.  The Name field is inside a another Array? [{"expanded":false,"items":[{"detail":{"Id":"asasasasasasas","Name":"CI-000358". How can I get the Name field if its inside another Array?